# Loading GeoJSON vector layer does not limit loading when setting maxResolution/minResolution

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I am using GeoJSON Vector layer that is loaded dynamically through a call to a server api method. This basically works, but it potentially loads a lot of features, so I want to limit the zoom level so it does not load when zoomed too far out.

I try to set `maxResolution` on the config, but this does not seem to have any effect.

Here is my <del>layer</del> source definition:

```
  var vectorFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    maxResolution: 1.2,
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
      var transformedExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, projection, 'EPSG:4326')
      self.loadGeoHashesJson(transformedExtent).then(function (response) {
        console.log('loadGeoHashesJson response:', response)
        var features = vectorFormat.readFeatures(response.body, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: projection })
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features)
      }, function (response) {
        console.error('error getting data from server', response)
      })
    }
  })
```

I also tried to check on the resolution inside the loader method, and skip loading the data if the resolution is larger than the maxResolution. This works initially, but it does not trigger load immediately when zoomed in to a valid resolution.  I have to pan about a bit to get to an area that has not been touched earlier for it to load again.

How can I get this to work so that the maxResolution is actively stopping the layer from loading when resolution is above maxResolution, and actually loading when the resolution goes below maxResolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maxResolution setting should be on the **layer** config, NOT the **source** config!

So when I moved the `maxResolution` setting to the initialization of the vector layer, it worked perfectly:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'GeoHash',
    maxResolution: 1.2,
    source: vectorSource
  })
```